# Resize on droppable is not working in Mozilla

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make one div droppable and resizable, it works great in Chrome, but not in Firefox.

Here is my jsFiddle please open this in the Firefox:
[***MY DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/c38WX/7/)

My code:

```js
// main drop function for work area
$('#img-drop-container').droppable({
  accept: '.img-drop',
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    var $clone = ui.helper.clone();
    if (!$clone.is('.inside-drop-zone')) {
      $(this).append($clone.addClass('inside-drop-zone').draggable({
        containment: '#img-drop-container',
        stack: '.inside-drop-zone',
        zIndex: 100,
        cursor: 'pointer'
      }));
      $clone.removeClass('img-drop');

      // resize image
      //   $('.inside-drop-zone').resizable({
      //   aspectRatio: true,
      //   handles: 'ne, se, sw, nw'
      //   });
    }
  }
});

//clone the draggable items
$('li .img-drop').draggable({
  helper: 'clone',
  cursor: 'pointer',
});
```

```css
ul {
    list-style:none;
}
#img-drop-container {
    background-color:#d8d8d8;
    border: 1px solid #9C9898;
    height:557px;
    width:99.9%;
}
.img-drop {
    height: 120px;
    width: auto;
}
#trash {
    float:left;
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-top:20px;
}
#trash {
    width:140px;
    height:140px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:center center;
    z-index:2;
}
img {
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
}
.store-thumb {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}
#imgbg {
    float: right;
    left: -2%;
    position: relative;
    top: 4%;
}
.column {
    margin-top: -21%;
    margin-left:55%;
}
.resizable {
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #bb0000;
}
.resizable img {
    width: 100%;
}
.ui-resizable-handle {
    background: #f5dc58;
    border: 1px solid #FFF;
    width: 9px;
    height: 9px;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<ul id="carousel" class="elastislide-list">
  <li>
    <div class="img-drop">
      <div style='resize: horizontal; height:20px; width: 100px; overflow: auto; border: solid gray 1px;float:left;  background-color: green;'></div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
<div id="img-drop-container"></div>
```

Comment: Basically you're saying the resize doesn't work in Firefox? Everything else seems to be OK.

Comment: yes , only resize is not working

Comment: should you be able to resize before it's dropped into the drop-zone?

Comment: Have you not try this on yours side, its also not working in the drop zone

Comment: Yes, if you've got a question go for it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64440/discussion-between-cold-coffee-and-mikehomme).

Comment: @mikehomme .... Have you tried with problem or got any solution????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c38WX/40/

**HTML:**
only one div in li

```
<div class="img-drop" style='height:20px; width: 100px; overflow: hidden; border: solid gray 1px;float:left;  background-color: green;'></div>
```

**JQ:**

add resizible widget

```
$('li .img-drop').draggable({
        helper: 'clone', 
       cursor: 'pointer',
    }).resizable({ 
        handles: "e" ,
        autoHide: true
    });
```

Comment: are you sure the link of js fiddle is updated one ,, coz it is not working on my both browsers, chrome firefox

Comment: print screens: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=314rswz&s=8#.VGYwx8mJfcw

http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=ncxf8g&s=8#.VGYwsMmJfcw

Comment: new fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fbwesfLr/. Yesterday I had a problem with the fiddle maybe today is the same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64957/discussion-between-cold-coffee-and-dm4web).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working Fiddle, perhaps not perfectly as I'm not exactly sure what the functionality should be.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/occursys/8twm5xkb/)**

Instead of using resize:horizontal, I'm using jQuery UI's resize (as it looks like you also tried) to hande the resize functionality. **handles: 'e, w'** is what restricts the resize to horizontal only.

```
// resize image
$('.resize_box').resizable({
    handles: 'e, w'
});
```

Comment: i am trying this at my end,

Comment: sure, don't miss the Fiddle link, the snippet of code above is only part of the change.